# Extract possessive words and word in brackets with Python regexp

Tags: python, regex

It is easy to extract them separately,

```
re.findall(r"\((\w+)\)", "It's Jane's cat Jack (male)") #1
re.findall("(?<=\()\w+(?=\))", "It's Jane's cat Jack (male)") #2
# ['male']

re.findall(r"\w+(?='s)", "It's Jane's cat Jack (male)")
# ['It', 'Jane']

re.findall(r"\S+", "It's Jane's cat Jack (male)")
# ["It's", "Jane's", 'cat', 'Jack (male)']
```

However it confuses me why

```
re.findall(r"\((\w+)\)|\w+(?='s)|\S+", "It's Jane's cat Jack (male)") #1
re.findall(r"(?<=\()\w+(?=\))|\w+(?='s)|\S+", "It's Jane's cat Jack (male)") #2
# ['It', "'s", 'Jane', "'s", 'cat', 'Jack', '(male)']
```

never produce:

```
# ['It', 'Jane', 'cat', 'Jack', 'male']
```

BTW, #1 or #2 which is better? They produce the same result.

Thanks for view & reply

Comment: Because the `\S+` would match the remaining `'s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this, since  the `\S+` would match one or more non-whitespace characters, this would also matches  the remaining `'s` . And also on comparing the two methods you gave, you must go with the second one since the first one should return `male` string and many empty strings because of capturing group present in your regex.

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?<=\()\w+(?=\))|\w+(?='s)|(?<!\S)\w+(?!\S)", "It's Jane's cat Jack (male)")
['It', 'Jane', 'cat', 'Jack', 'male']
```

or

```
>>> [i for i in re.split(r"\s*(?:[()]|'s|\s)\s*", "It's Jane's cat Jack (male)") if i]
['It', 'Jane', 'cat', 'Jack', 'male']
```

Comment: Thank you, they both work as I want. But I wonder why the parentheses in square brackets do not prefixed by backslash\ ?`r"\s*(?:[()]|'s|\s)\s*"`

Comment: because brackets `(`, `)` looses it's special meaning inside a character class ie, `[]`